# TimeStamp in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am programming a database-first application with Entity Framework 4. I want to use a `timestamp` column for checking the concurrency. So I created a column in my table called `ts` with a `timestamp` datatype.

In Visual Studio 2010 I updated the model from database in my `.edmx` file. Then I changed the concurrency mode to "Fixed" and `Store Generated Pattern` to `Computed`. In application all records are listed in listview and I can select any of them and edit them from listview.

When I want to show all records in listview, I did the following:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(cableApplication.Id.ToString());
item.SubItems.Add(cableApplication.Application);
item.SubItems.Add(cableApplication.DefaultSize.ToString());
item.SubItems.Add(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(cableApplication.ts));
lv1.Items.Add(item);
```

Now when I trace the value of the `ts` variable in watch window, I see `byte[8] :0,0,0,0,0,0,18,178`
Suppose I want to edit the record I create a new instance of the entity and pass it to the form  like the following

```
CableApplication cableApplication = new CableApplication(id,lv1.FocusedItem.SubItems[1].Text,lv1.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text,Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lv1.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text),State.Modified);     

FormCableApplication formCableApplication = new FormCableApplication(cableApplication);
                if (formCableApplication.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (SaveObject(cableApplication, "CableApplications"))
                    {
                        //// Something here
                    }
                }
```

If it is the first time that I want to edit the record I have the value of

```
byte[8] :0,0,0,0,0,0,18,178    (or whatever is in above)
```

for the `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lv1.FocusedItem.SubItems[4].Text)` in watch window, but if it is the second time or above that I edit a record I get the value `0,0,0,0,0,0,18,63` (always this value) for the `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lv1.FocusedItem.SubItems[4].Text)` in watch window.

So I get this error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Why is this happening? Why in second time the value has been changed without any has happened to it (no edit , or nothing else)? I am developing this program alone so definitely no one has changed or deleted the data?

I am completely confused with this `timestamp` in Entity Framework.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not totally clear what you did but TimeStamp is a badly named revision-id. It can change when it wants, don't mess with it. It's not for showing in the GUI.

Comment: should't i read the timestamp field into the field of my entity?this is my model<br>  public partial class CableApplication : StateObject
    {
        public CableApplication()
        {            
        }
    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Application { get; set; }
        public double DefaultSize { get; set; }
        public byte[] ts { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Yes it has to be in your model. But not on your screen and you should never assign to it. Not clear if what you're doing is a form of debugging but adding it to the ListView may cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Solved. as I am using entity Disconnected, so I Use
 byte[] tstamp
in my model class and in the UI I use

```
public static string CreateEtag(byte[] Timestamp)
{
if (Timestamp == null)
  return String.Empty;
//convert the timestamp to a string and get it into the etag format W/"'hexString'" 
StringBuilder etag = new StringBuilder("W/\"X'");
etag.Append(BitConverter.ToString(Timestamp).Replace("-", ""));
etag.Append("'\"");
return etag.ToString();
}
```

to make tstamp to string
and

```
public static byte[] CreateTimestamp(string Etag)
{
    var timestamp = new List<byte>();
    var strippedEtag = Etag.Split('\'')[1];
    var byteStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, strippedEtag.Length / 2).Select(i => strippedEtag.Substring(i * 2, 2)).ToList();
    return Enumerable.Range(0, strippedEtag.Length)
                  .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                  .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(strippedEtag.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                  .ToArray();
 }
```

to make tstamp string to byte[]
that solved my problem. I found this solution in the internet